# How can I order a child flex element ahead of its parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML/CSS setup ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjwdtbsp/1/)):

```css
.flex-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.one, .two, .three {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.one {
  order:0;
}

.two {
  order:1;
}

.three {
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="three">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, my aim is to order div `.one` at the top. The problem is that this div is *inside* a flex div with a different `order`.

## What I've tried so far

1. `position:absolute` or `fixed` on `.one`. While that works, I need all the divs to be blocks.
2. I have move the `.one` div to the parent div using javascript, but the aim is to do this *without* JS.

Any viable solution to this?

Comment: You would need a bit of js or to flatten the structure so the three divs were on the same level - or have one or three in that last div - it's the worst place for the 2 div!

Comment: What is in each div and is any of them a fixed height, or are they all dynamic content?

Comment: They are all dynamic unfortunately.

Comment: Nope, can't be done w/o script if the height of the elements is dynamic/content based

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing the whole concept behind `order`. It's designed to allow re-arranging of siblings. If you want to display `.two` between `.one` and `.three` at a certain screen width and outside of them at other widths:

- **they should be siblings**
- **there is absolutely no point** in `.one` being a child of `.three`.

So, I'd use a *mobile first* layout:

```css
.flex-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.two {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05)
  }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .two { order:1; }
  .one,.three { order: 2; }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
</div>
```

However, if `.one` ***must*** be a child of `.three` (btw, when you start using this verb in web development, it's solid sign you're doing it wrong) - your only choice is JavaScript. Now the problem with js driven `@media` queries is that you need to be a cross-browser/cross-device ninja to detect the change of `@media` query interval in all browser/device combos and that's why you should use [`enquire.js`](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) for it. And, of course, move `.two` around in DOM.

---

But really, since I tried my best to answer your question, it would mean a lot to me if you tried your best to answer mine: why does the markup need to remain unchanged? Does the markup matter? Or does the way your contents are displayed cross-browser/cross-device matter?

Comment: There are plenty of cases where a front end engineer is at the mercy of the back end engineers' work, sometimes years later.

Comment: I fully agree. That's why you can't be a CSS expert nowadays without being a JS expert.